# SelectedIndexChanged of asp:DropDownList not firing in li

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have issue with SelectedIndexChanged of DropDownList control. Bellow is my code.

Setting up the dropdownlist

```
<div class="add-contact-contet-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><span style="display: inline-block;">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddActionType" runat="server" CssClass="action-textbox slct-wdth-162px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddActionType_SelectedIndexChanged" OnTextChanged="ddActionType_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="True">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Page_Load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
         loadDropDownLists();
}
```

Binding the dropdownlist

```
private void loadDropDownLists()
{
    ActionTypeCtrl atCtrl = new ActionTypeCtrl();
    this.ddActionType.Items.Clear();
    this.ddActionType.Items.Add("-Action Type-");
    this.ddActionType.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
    this.ddActionType.DataSource = atCtrl.getActionTypeList();
    this.ddActionType.DataTextField = "ActionTypeName";
    this.ddActionType.DataValueField = "ID";
    this.ddActionType.DataBind();
}
```

dropdownlist selectedindexchange event

```
protected void ddActionType_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ActionTypeCtrl atCtrl = new ActionTypeCtrl();
    string url = atCtrl.GetActypeUrl(ddActionType.SelectedValue.ToString());
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

It loads the page on every click but does not fire dropdownlist event. I have same scenario in other project where it is working fine. I dont know what is the issue. Any idea???

Regards,

Raja

Comment: What is the problem??

Comment: Does not fire ddActionType_SelectedIndexChanged event but fires page_load on every click.

Comment: why are you giving same name(`ddActionType_SelectedIndexChanged`) to OnTextChanged="ddActionType_SelectedIndexChanged" when you gave OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddActionType_SelectedIndexChanged"

Comment: Remove `OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddActionType_SelectedIndexChanged" OnTextChanged="ddActionType_SelectedIndexChanged"`.

Comment: Yes, I was checking with both and seperately. I removed OnTextChanged="ddActionType_SelectedIndexChanged" but its still not work.

Comment: @user3209264 Remove both.

Comment: I removed both but not worked. Even ddActionType_SelectedIndexChanged event in code behind is present but no error.

Comment: Remove if (!Page.IsPostBack) line from your code and then check..

Comment: @rr_only4you WHY ? No, DO NOT remove if(!Page.IsPostBack) !! Its totally fine. Have you allready tried to debug and set a debug-point to the Page_load and see if it loads when you change the index ? Do you use UpdatePanels ?

Comment: @DatRid I debug-point to Page_Load and it loads when i change the index of dropdownlist. First time it bind the list and second time it refreshes the page and empty the list but Page_Load get fired on every index change of dropdownlist. But ddActionType_SelectedIndexChanged does not fire at all.

Comment: @user3209264 Huh ? The DropDownList becomes empty when you change the index twice ? So if you change it, it makes a postback. Good. Have you tried to set a breakpoint also to `ddActionType_SelectedIndex` and see if it fires then, and the code there maybe just doesnt works ?

Comment: @DatRid I set a breakpoint on ddActionType_SelectedIndex but it does not fire. I used like this. <div class="add-contact-contet-wrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><span style="display: inline-block;">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddActionType" runat="server" CssClass="action-textbox slct-wdth-162px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddActionType_SelectedIndexChanged" OnTextChanged="ddActionType_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="True" EnableViewState="True">
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>